# Discord.py Buttons (Not in embed)

Tags: discord.py

So I came across a bot called GameBot, and when you send a command, it sends buttons like so:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oylb.png)

an anyone tell me how they did this??

Comment: Discord has added the support for buttons, but they are not yet implementented in discord.py yet, there are other 3rd party libraries that can do this but I siggest waiting for discord.py to officially add this since it is being worked upon

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are a new discord feature that are not yet supported by the official discord.py library.

There is however a third party library called `discord components` that is mentioned above, however, it is best to wait until it is supported by discord.py

There is currently no ETA on when buttons and slash commands will be supported however it will be a lot more beneficial to wait than use third party services.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new Discord feature. I personally use this feature for my bot too since the discord-buttons library is outdated, you can use the [discord-components](https://pypi.org/project/discord-components/) library instead.